# Why is this scrolling vertically rather than horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this code to scroll horizontally, but for some reason it scrolls vertically. Place your cursor over the images and scroll down to see what I mean.

How can I get this to scroll horizontally instead? It has overflow x as scroll. So all images will be on the same row rather than 2 rows like it is now.

```css
#images-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;

  position: static;
}
#main-image {
  width: 80.5%;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 53.666%;

  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 66.666%;
}
#image-thumbs {
  width: 17.5%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;

  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.image-thumb {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 66.666%;

  width: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 16.666%;
  float: left;
}

#test-ar {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 16.666%;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  /* overflow-y: hidden; */
}
```

```html
<div id="images-wrap">
  <div id='test-ar'>
    <div id="image-thumbs" style="overflow: hidden;">
      <div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/394545.jpg')"></div>
      <div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/572806.jpg')"></div>
      <div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486757.jpg')"></div>
      <div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486757.jpg')"></div>
      <div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486757.jpg')"></div>
      <div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486757.jpg')"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the requested demo of the flex version. Images have been replaced with placeholder images, as the original ones no longer seem to work.

```css
#image-thumbs {
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.image-thumb {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: auto;
    width: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 16.666%;
    flex: 1 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-thumbs">
    <div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150')"></div>
    <div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150')"></div>
    <div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150')"></div>
    <div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150')"></div>
    <div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150')"></div>
    <div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150')"></div>
</div>
```

Also [a demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/wjebdE).

Comment: thanks for trying to help. I still can't apply your solution and have no idea why. I've made a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/42kdsema/), where this post shows on mobile view of the fiddle, and scroll-x just doesn't happen. Same rules you mentioned have been applied, flex, nowrap, scroll to the same elements, but nothing. Completely baffled

Comment: Your example there is way different than the question. 
1. Remove `overflow: hidden` from `#image-thumbs`, which is overriding your x-scroll. Inline elements always override CSS classes. https://jsfiddle.net/42kdsema/2/

Comment: wow - I can't believe I was so daft. Didn't notice the inline style, which was obviously a big problem. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of floating the elements, use `display: inline-block` for all the image thumbs, and set it's parent to not wrap inline elements using `white-space: nowrap`. To remove whitespace between the individual image thumbs, you can simply comment the line breaks out:

```css
#images-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  float: left;
}
#image-thumbs {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 2%;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;

  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.image-thumb {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 66.666%;

  width: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 16.666%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#test-ar {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 16.666%;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="images-wrap">
  <div id='test-ar'>
    <div id="image-thumbs">
      <div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/394545.jpg')"></div><!--
      --><div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/572806.jpg')"></div><!--
      --><div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486757.jpg')"></div><!--
      --><div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486757.jpg')"></div><!--
      --><div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486757.jpg')"></div><!--
      --><div class="image-thumb" style="background-image: url('https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/486757.jpg')"></div><!--
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems to be ok without comments - or am i missing something as to why they were included?

Comment: @user8758206 the comments remove white space between the inline block elements.

Comment: but not having the comments works also, so the comments seem to do nothing

Comment: @user8758206 Then by all means leave the comments out hah

Comment: ah ok, just thought I was not understanding something as surely they were put in for a reason!

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help. No idea why, but your solution doesn’t work on the real thing. I’ve made a JS fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/64cmymdd/) and applied the same rules, but doesn’t want to work (on the mobile view of fiddle). Really curious to know why, and trying to become a better developer. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Remove all references to `width` and `float`, make the outer container an unwrapping `flex`, and make all inner elements `flex: 1 0 25%`.

```
/* Outer container */
#image-thumbs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

/* Inner elements */
.image-thumb {
  flex: 1 0 25%
}
```

If you need a demo, I can create one for you.

Comment: yes please! I've tried to replicate your solution, but the overflow-x isn't scrolling

Comment: i also thought giving #image-thumbs a display flex and flex-wrap nowrap would do it, but it just shrinks the width of the thumbs to fit in the container